# Parsing googleapi output php

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I'm new with PHP. I'm trying to get youtube video details from api. My try is,

```
public static function get_statistics($id=""){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id='.$id.'&key=<api_key>');
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $obj = json_decode($result);
  $items = $obj->items;
  return $items;
  }
```

google api output is

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/3rwcD8mpPjKqGuWm_i6VncLIf8Y\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/G0FH__iOsQSluyo6j8IQWdxgcCI\"",
   "id": "TruIq5IxuiU",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "19736248",
    "likeCount": "119522",
    "dislikeCount": "3710",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "22205"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I get the "viewCount" from the above output

Answer (score 0):

You can get the viewcount with a simple regex and the php preg_match function ([Php.net Pregmatch()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php)):

Here's an exemple :

```
     $string = '{
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
     "etag": ""q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/3rwcD8mpPjKqGuWm_i6VncLIf8Y"",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 1,
      "resultsPerPage": 1
     },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#video",
       "etag": ""q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/G0FH__iOsQSluyo6j8IQWdxgcCI"",
       "id": "TruIq5IxuiU",
       "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "19736248",
        "likeCount": "119522",
        "dislikeCount": "3710",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "22205"
       }
      }
     ]
    }';
    preg_match('/viewCount": "(.*?)"/', $string, $viewCount );
    $viewCount = $viewCount[1];
    echo $viewCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the google sdk for PHP. 
It's easy to set up and it'll give you objects as return.

It's available here : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/